# Check for Cookie ; load() if cookie matches, need to reload to see new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cookies

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var hrefs = {
    "en": ["includes/test1.html", "includes/test2.html"],
    "es": ["includes/test3.html", "includes/test4.html"]
  }
  $(function() {
    var cookie = Cookies.get('langCookie');
    if (cookie) {
      $("#div1").load(hrefs[cookie][0]);
      $("#div2").load(hrefs[cookie][1]);
    }
    $("[hreflang]").on("click", function() {
      var lang = $(this).attr("hreflang");
      Cookies.set('langCookie', lang);
      $("#div1").load(hrefs[lang][0]);
      $("#div2").load(hrefs[lang][1]);
    });
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
<a href="#" hreflang="en" onclick="window.lang.change('en'); return false;">English</a> | <a href="#" hreflang="es" onclick="window.lang.change('es'); return false;">Spanish</a>
```

Having issues with loading content based on Cookie value.

My div is set up this way:

```
<div id="prs"> </div>
```

I have a pseudo language switcher, that if based on cookie, should load an html file into the div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cookie = Cookies.get('langCookie');
if((cookie) === 'en')
{
$("#prs").empty();
$("#prs").load("includes/test.html");
}
else if((cookie) === 'th'){
$("#prs").empty();
$("#prs").load("includes/test2.html");
}
else if((cookie) === 'es'){
$("#prs").empty();
$("#prs").load("includes/test3.html");
}
```

However, when I click on the link to switch Language, the cookie is set however I have to reload the page to see the new content. As you can see in my script above, I tried to initiate an "empty()" on the div before the loading of the content. this of course doesn't work. I've read that the issue could be related to the $(document).ready(fucntion)

How can I call it so that the div is reloaded with the content, once the cookie is set to the new language, and the div is updated with the correct loaded html file?

edit to add:

HTML for Language switching (link based):

```
<div id="langChanger"><a href="#" onclick="window.lang.change('en'); return false;">Switch to English</a> | <a href="#" onclick="window.lang.change('th'); return false;">Switch to Thai</a> | <a href="#" onclick="window.lang.change('es'); return false;">Switch to Spanish</a></div>
```

---

Update: included snippet below per request. Using js-cookie.js to create cookie.

Comment: Where is your code where you set the cookie to a new language?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}) only runs once the page has downloaded to the browser. The code you have written will only execute with a page load/refresh.

Comment: Yes, I figured that would be the issue. How do I correct for it?

Comment: Can you use LocalStorage instead of cookies? If so you could use a StorageEvent to detect when the value changes

Comment: Using cookies because I need the translations persistent across the site (7 pages).

Comment: Yeah localstorage would work for that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work better.
Note the unobtrusive event handling and usage of the actual variable instead of testing it every time

```js
var hrefs = {
  "en": "includes/test.html",
  "th": "includes/test2.html",
  "es": "includes/test3.html"
}
$(function() {
  var cookie = Cookies.get('langCookie');
  if (cookie) {
    $("#prs").load(hrefs[cookie]);
  }
  $("[hreflang]").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr("hreflang");
    Cookies.set('langCookie', lang);
    $("#prs").load(hrefs[lang]);
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="langChanger">
  <a href="#" hreflang="en">Switch to English</a> |
  <a href="#" hreflang="th">Switch to Thai</a> |
  <a href="#" hreflang="es">Switch to Spanish</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! Question, if I have say 3 html files that need to be loaded per language into 3 different divs, would I need to put that in an array?

Comment: Sure: `var hrefs={ "en" : ["url1.html","url2.html","url3.html"], "es": [....], "th":[....]}` using `hrefs[lang][0]` to load the first one

Comment: or `var hrefs={ "en" : { "div1" :"url1.html", "div2":"url2.html" ....` and use `$("divselector").load(hrefs[lang][$("divselector").attr(id)]`

Comment: Thank you! Had to fix your solution a bit (my other content wasn't changing), but overall it worked as I needed it to.

Comment: Hi sorry, but when I try to load the multiple loads into different divs, the load() fails to execute.

Comment: Unfortunatley jsfiddle is blocked where I am.

Comment: Gist? Codepen? Your own site?

Comment: all blocked. internal server development unfortunately.

Comment: Please add an update to your question with the code. Click the `<>` snippet editor to create a [mcve]

Comment: You are trying to load multiple divs at the same time? Don't. Load them one at a time by calling the next load in the success of the previous. Show me some code somewhere and I can help

Comment: `var hrefs = {
 "en": ["includes/test1.html", "includes/test2.html"],
 "es": ["includes/test3.html", "test4.html"]
}
$(function() {
var cookie = Cookies.get('langCookie');
  if (cookie) {
  $("#div1").load(hrefs[cookie][0]);
  $("#div2").load(hrefs[cookie][1]);
  }
$("[hreflang]").on("click", function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr("hreflang");
  Cookies.set('langCookie', lang);
  $("#div1").load(hrefs[lang][0]);
  $("#div2").load(hrefs[lang][1]);
   });
})`

Comment: snippet included in OP